# В приложение калькулятор добавить возможность ввода цифр и операций с помощью клавиатуры Javascript

Tags: javascript

Добавить в приложение возможность ввода цифр и операций с нумпада. 
Как реализовать?

```js
var inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');

function addSymbolToInput(number) {
    if (inputField.value === '0') {
        inputField.value = number;
    } else {
        inputField.value += number;
    };
};

function deleteLastSymbol() {
    var subStr = inputField.value.slice(0, -1)
    inputField.value = subStr === '' ? '0' : subStr;
};

function deleteAllSymbols() {
    inputField.value = 0;
};

function getResult() {
    inputField.value = eval(inputField.value);
};
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.calculator {
    width: 420px;
    height: 610px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: auto;
}

.calculator__display {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 31px;
}

.calculator__display--textview {
    width: 360px;
    height: 90px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #a6e6e9, darkgray);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

table {
    margin: auto;
}

.calculator__btn {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #f3ede3, #afaca8);
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.calculator__btn--stronger {
    width: 164px;
    height: 80px;
}

.calculator__btn--longer  {
    width: 80px;
    height: 164px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>HTML Калькулятор</title>
        <link href="calc.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="calculator__display">
                <input disabled class="calculator__display--textview" name="textview" id="inputField" type="text" value="0">
            </div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--red" onclick="deleteAllSymbols('AC')">AC</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--red" onclick="deleteLastSymbol()">C</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--orange" onclick="addSymbolToInput('/')">/</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--orange" onclick="addSymbolToInput('*')">*</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('7')">7</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('8')">8</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('9')">9</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--orange" onclick="addSymbolToInput('-')">-</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('4')">4</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('5')">5</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('6')">6</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--orange" onclick="addSymbolToInput('+')">+</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('1')">1</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('2')">2</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('3')">3</button>
                    </td>
                    <td  rowspan="2">
                        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--longer calculator__btn--orange" onclick="getResult('=')">=</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--stronger" onclick="addSymbolToInput('0')">0</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('.')">.</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script src="calc.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');

function addSymbolToInput(number) {
  if (inputField.value === '0') {
    inputField.value = number;
  } else {
    inputField.value += number;
  };
};

function deleteLastSymbol() {
  var subStr = inputField.value.slice(0, -1)
  inputField.value = subStr === '' ? '0' : subStr;
};

function deleteAllSymbols() {
  inputField.value = 0;
};

function getResult() {
  inputField.value = eval(inputField.value);
};

var SYMBOL_KEYCODES = {
  '45': '0',
  '35': '1',
  '40': '2',
  '34': '3',
  '37': '4',
  '12': '5',
  '39': '6',
  '36': '7',
  '38': '8',
  '33': '9',
  '107': '-',
  '109': '+',
  '106': '*',
  '111': '/',
  '46': '.'
};
var ENTER_KEYCODE = 13;
var BACKSPACE_KEYCODE = 8;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode in SYMBOL_KEYCODES) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    addSymbolToInput(SYMBOL_KEYCODES[evt.keyCode])
  } else if (evt.keyCode === ENTER_KEYCODE) {
    getResult();
  } else if (evt.keyCode === BACKSPACE_KEYCODE) {
    deleteLastSymbol();
  }
});
```

```css
.calculator {
  width: 420px;
  height: 610px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}

.calculator__display {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 31px;
}

.calculator__display--textview {
  width: 360px;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #a6e6e9, darkgray);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

.calculator__btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #f3ede3, #afaca8);
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.calculator__btn--stronger {
  width: 164px;
  height: 80px;
}

.calculator__btn--longer {
  width: 80px;
  height: 164px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="calculator__display">
    <input disabled class="calculator__display--textview" name="textview" id="inputField" type="text" value="0">
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--red" onclick="deleteAllSymbols('AC')">AC</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--red" onclick="deleteLastSymbol()">C</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--orange" onclick="addSymbolToInput('/')">/</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--orange" onclick="addSymbolToInput('*')">*</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('7')">7</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('8')">8</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('9')">9</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--orange" onclick="addSymbolToInput('-')">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('4')">4</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('5')">5</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('6')">6</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--orange" onclick="addSymbolToInput('+')">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('1')">1</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('2')">2</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('3')">3</button>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--longer calculator__btn--orange" onclick="getResult('=')">=</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <button class="calculator__btn calculator__btn--stronger" onclick="addSymbolToInput('0')">0</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="calculator__btn" onclick="addSymbolToInput('.')">.</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```